# HTTP and custom TCP server with actix-web

Tags: rust, tcp, webserver, actix-web

I have a REST API service written in Rust with Actix Web, but now it needs to accept connections from a GPS tracker.

The GPS tracker report its position opening a TCP connection and sending data directly as a text stream, not a HTTP connection.

I know I should probably accept these connections in another port, but I have no clue how to implement it, since actix-web doesn't provide a way to create a TCP socket server.

For now I have a small Python script that receives the messages from the GPS trackers and does a POST request to the Rust service, but it is very hacky.

Is it possible to receive raw TCP and HTTP requests in the same binary with Actix Web?

Comment: Just because your application has Actix-Web doesn't mean Actix-Web has to handle everything for you. All you need is to create a thread and listen for TCP connections. There's [`TcpListener`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html) for that.

Comment: Actix does include a generic [TCP server](https://docs.rs/actix-server/2.1.1/actix_server/)…